# How to sort legends alphabetically in plotly dash with category_orders function

Tags: python

I am using Plotly dash for creating a scatter plot. The legends I am getting in the final figure are randomly placed. I want to sort labels alphabetically from A to Z with `category_orders`.

```
fig = px.box(
        df,
        x=selected_x,
        y=selected_y,
        points='all',
        hover_data=hover_data,
        color=colour_by,
        width=800,
        height=600,
        labels={
            selected_y: "{} {}".format(selected_y_gene, selected_y),
            selected_x: "{} {}".format(selected_x_gene, selected_x),
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you construct the figure could you try sorting the values in the dataframe in the order you require? Thus set the True/False flag according to what you want.

```
orderedDF = df.sort_values(
  by=col_label, 
  ascending=True)
```

then add the following into the plot denoting the labels:

```
sort=False
```

Thus added below.

```
fig = px.box(
    orderedDF,
    x=selected_x,
    y=selected_y,
    points='all',
    hover_data=hover_data,
    color=colour_by,
    width=800,
    height=600,
    labels={
        selected_y: "{} {}".format(selected_y_gene, selected_y),
        selected_x: "{} {}".format(selected_x_gene, selected_x),
# I think it should go here
        sort=False
    }
    )
```

The gist is you are wanting to stop the automated re-ordering and force the dataframe order onto it.